# Why is my site's landing page ranking below the about page on Google?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

When I search for my site ("twolips dating"), the organic search results has the "about" page listed above the landing page.

[image: Twolips Dating brand search result]

This isn't desirable because I want my linked Google+ brand to show on the right side of the search results with additional site links below the main search result (like Microsoft below).

[image: Microsoft brand search result]

I've linked my Google+ brand to my site and verified it. I've also added the proper schema.org tags to my landing page. How can I guarantee that my landing page is the top link?

Comment: One hint: Look at your title tags. Try reversing them. The title tag is the primary semantic indication as to what a page is about.

Comment: AFAIK you misunderstand what a landing page is for. The web is a web of interconnected pages not a street of doorways.  You shouldn't be trying to herd people into an entrance page but expecting them to link in directly to relevant pages. Landing pages should be adding targets not funneling.

Comment: @JamesRyan I'm not really sure how you came to that conclusion as my question simply asked about the ordering of pages on Google Search. Perhaps I used the wrong terminology when I say "landing page"?

Comment: @JustinSkiles because if your about page has more relevant terms to their search it *should* be higher in the search results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Google thinks your "about" page is more relevant to the phrase being searched for.

Just looking at the keywords... The phrase you are searching for appears verbatim in both the title and description of the "about" page, yet does not appear at all in the title or main text of the homepage. So, based purely on the raw text, why should your homepage appear first?

However, search for "twolips games" (which does at least appear in the title of your homepage) and as if by magic your homepage appears first.

Comment: I just left a comment about the title tags and suggested switching them. ;-0 Ooopppsss!! You hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @w3d, thanks, I understand, but the strange thing is that the trailing `- Twolips Dating` in the top search result doesn't exist in my HTML. Is Google tacking that on for some reason?

Comment: @JustinSkiles This is Google branding your SERP link. This is done when a title tag is short. You can change this by making making the title longer. But do not go over 45-50 characters (really 512 pixels). Then you can get another oddity that you may not want. Cheers!!

Comment: @JustinSkiles But "Twolips Dating" does appear in an `H1` tag near the top of the page. And, as closetnoc suggests, Google does/can change the title and description in the SERPs to better reflect the phrase being search for.